# How to append icon to input - after typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a check icon after validating fields, I've done [This](https://fiddle.jshell.net/roybarak/w7ymefax/4/)
and i don't want to use hide/show for adding the check mark - because it's adding them to all the inputs.. that's why I've tried to use append()... but i don't know why it's not working. I've added 2 examples - the first is for you to understand what i wish to achieve - and the second is what i'm trying to do with append.

So this is working partially :

```
    <h2>
    without append
    </h2>
    <hr>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cont">
        <input type="text" class="params_input form-control">
        <span class="params_icon"></span>
      </div>


      <div class="cont">
        <input type="text" class="params_input_phone form-control" maxlength="10">
        <span class="params_icon"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <h2>
    with append
    </h2>
    <hr>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cont">
        <input type="text" class="params_input_2 form-control">

      </div>


      <div class="cont">
        <input type="text" class="params_input_phone_2 form-control" maxlength="10">

      </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
             .params_icon:before {
       content: "\f00c";
       font-family: FontAwesome;
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: normal;
       text-decoration: inherit;
       --adjust as necessary-- color: #000;
       font-size: 18px;
       padding-right: 0.5em;
       position: absolute;
       top: 4px;
       right: 0;
       color: #49c8c1;
     }

     .params_icon {
       display: none;
     }



     p {
       color: red;
     }

     .cont {
       display: flex;
       position: relative;
     }

     .wrapper {
       display: flex;
     }
```

JS :

```
           <!-- without append
     -->
     $(".params_input").keyup(function() {

      if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
        $('.params_icon').show();
      } else {
        $('.params_icon').hide();
      }

    });

    $(".params_input_phone").keyup(function() {

      if ($(this).val().length === 10) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
        $('.params_icon').show();
      }

    });
    <!-- with append
     -->
      $(".params_input_2").keyup(function() {

      if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
        $(this).append('<span class="params_icon"></span>');
      } 

    });

    $(".params_input_phone_2").keyup(function() {

      if ($(this).val().length === 10) {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
        $(this).append('<span class="params_icon"></span>');
      }

    });
```

Comment: This what your looking for https://fiddle.jshell.net/w7ymefax/6/

Comment: change `$('.params_icon').show()` by `$(this).parent().find('.params_icon').show();`

Comment: Carsten Løvbo Andersen - Thanks!!!!

Comment: I don't see any problem in your example if you toggle the visibility by 'show' / 'hide'. Is there any specific reason? I'm just curious.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**.  Not all the code is in the question, causing some confusion.

Comment: What the accepted answer and other miss to catch is that your icon is getting added multiple times, check my answer for the correct one.

Comment: @RoyBarOn please update the question to include all the code.

Comment: freedomn-m - I'm sorry -i  didn't quit understood what it is you want me to do... the question is very clear...therefore i received many suggestions....

Comment: @RoyBarOn apologies if not clear - the code in your question only includes the code for 'without append' - there's additional code for 'with append' in your fiddle that is not in the question.  All relevant code should be in the question in-case the third-party website becomes unavailable.   The valid answers you've received were based on the fiddle.   I'm asking that you (always) include the (relevant) code in the question as per [mcve] (the complete part).

Comment: freedomn-m - Ok - I've update - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you `.params_icon` has `display: none;`, but also there is other issues I will clear out

**EDIT**
What others fail to find here is the bigger issue. That your `param_icon` gets added mutiple times, if you write 40 chars in the inbox it will be added 37 times. You *should* avoid that by checking if it exist before adding.

[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/w7ymefax/7/)

```
$(".params_input_2").keyup(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.val().length > 3) {
    var $parent = $this.parent('.cont');
    var $icon = $parent.find('.params_icon');

    if ($icon.length <= 0) {
      $(this).parent('.cont').append('<span class="params_icon"></span>');
    }
  }

});
```

**btw** you can solve the show issue with pure css if you like with this

```
 .params_input_2 + .params_icon {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: @freedomn-m he does not trigger a `show()` on his second example, check the code before posting

Comment: @freedomn-m please show me the `show()` on `.params_input_2` trigger

Comment: ... please show me the .params_input_2 trigger ... *in the question*  :)

Comment: As you can see, the issue here is that OP has not included all the code in the question - you're answering the *fiddle* which I didn't look at as all the code is *supposed to be* in the question.  (hence my asking if I'm missing something - I was missing the *hidden code*)

Comment: @freedomn-m you should *read the question fully* before jumping on everybody like you had the solution, as you did not. Also deleting comments and modifying like that was what you meant all the time shows just how serious you are.

Comment: I disagree.  The question should contain all the code necessary, as per the 'close question vote' option: "and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**".   As I stated above, the "code" in the question does not contain the same code that you answer, which is clear if you "read the **question** fully".  Neither the question nor the answer should be based on additional code **hidden** away on a third-party site.  Reading the "question fully" as you put it should not mean also reading additional code on a third party site, so I *had* read the **question** fully.

Comment: I deleted my comment as you had, as I asked, showed me what I was missing - ie the **hidden** code - so that comment was no longer relevant as your answer was correct, based on the **hidden** code that was not in the question (where it should be).

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `$(this).siblings('.params_icon').show();` not `$('.params_icon').show();` as you are just targeting each `'.params_icon` not just the one that has been edited

Answer (score 0):

Use `(this).next('.params_icon').show();` to get the `params_icon` element next to the input your typing in

**Demo below** or [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/w7ymefax/6/)

```js
$(".params_input").keyup(function() {

  if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
    $(this).next('.params_icon').show();
  } else {
    $(this).next('.params_icon').hide();
  }

});

$(".params_input_phone").keyup(function() {

  if ($(this).val().length === 10) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
    $(this).next('.params_icon').show();
  }

});
```

```css
.params_icon:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  --adjust as necessary-- color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 0;
  color: #49c8c1;
}

.params_icon {
  display: none;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="params_input form-control">
  <span class="params_icon">icon</span>
</div>


<div class="cont">
  <input type="text" class="params_input_phone form-control" maxlength="10">
  <span class="params_icon">icon</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: While nothing wrong with this *in this scenario*, I'd add a caveat when using `.next(".class")` as it doesn't do what most people expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
<!-- with append
 -->
  $(".params_input_2").keyup(function() {

  if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
    $(this).parent().append('<span class="params_icon2"></span>');
    //$(this).append('<span class="params_icon2"></span>');
  } 

});

$(".params_input_phone_2").keyup(function() {

  if ($(this).val().length === 10) {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
    $(this).parent().append('<span class="params_icon2"></span>');
  }

});
```

**CSS**

```
 .params_icon:before, .params_icon2:before {
   content: "\f00c";
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: inherit;
   --adjust as necessary-- color: #000;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding-right: 0.5em;
   position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
   right: 0;
   color: #49c8c1;
 }

 .params_icon {
   display: none;
 }
 .params_icon2 {
   display: block;
 }
```

The first point is that `.params_icon{display: none}`.

So you should make it `display: inline-block | block | etc..`

I made another class `.params_icon2`.

The second is that `$(this).append('<span class="params_icon2"></span>');` is wrong.

You should change like that `$(this).parent().append('<span class="params_icon2"></span>');`